# Connect remote scylla db server shows error

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have installed scylla-db in google cloud servers.

**Steps i have followed:**

```
sudo yum install epel-release

sudo curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/scylla.repo -L http://repositories.scylladb.com/scylla/repo/a2a0ba89d456770dfdc1cd70325e3291/centos/scylladb-2.0.repo

sudo yum install scylla

sudo scylla_setup

(Given yes to "verify supportable version" , " verify packages" , "core dump", " fstim ssd "
For remaining : Given NO)

IN  file :/etc/scylla.d/io.conf

SEASTAR_IO="--max-io-requests=12 --num-io-queues=1"
( edited this file manually )

sudo systemctl start scylla-server
```

It shows: Cannot able to read yaml file. Then google it and downgraded the yaml-cpp version to 0.5.1 from 0.5.3 version.
*then 
scylla-server started running .*

```
[root@scylla ~]# nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  208.69 KB  256          ?       888e91da-9385-4c61-8417-dd59c1a979b8  rack1
Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless


[root@scylla ~]# cat /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml | grep seeds:
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1"
[root@scylla ~]# cat /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml | grep rpc_address:
rpc_address: localhost
#broadcast_rpc_address: 
[root@scylla ~]# cat /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml | grep listen_address:
listen_address: localhost

[root@scylla ~]# cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.8 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> exit



[root@scylla ~]# netstat -tupln | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6387/scylla         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6387/scylla         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1105/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6387/scylla         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1119/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9180            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6387/scylla         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9160          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6387/scylla         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5217/httpd          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1105/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::35063                :::*                    LISTEN      6412/scylla-jmx     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1119/master         
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          :::*                    LISTEN      6412/scylla-jmx
```

scylla-server is running.

Same setup was done another server 
Server Name scylla-db-1

I need to connect to the server scylla ( IP: xx.xx.xxx) from this server.

when i execute the below :

```
[root@scylla-db-1 ~]# cqlsh xx.xx.xxx
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'xx.xx.xxx': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('xx.xx.xxx', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

**How to connect the remote server from this server?**

Also 
while checking the http://xx.xx.xxx:10000  and http://xx.xx.xxx:10000/ui in the browser , I m getting problem loading page.

Note :

> I have done editing the /etc/scylla.d/io.conf file for assigning the
>   max-io-requests manually

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Port 10000 is the rest api for scylla and is usually left bounded to the 127.0.0.1 - thats why you can not access it

To gain access via cql you need to edit the /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml file and set the rpc_address

Please follow the instructions for configuring scylla for a cluster deployment: single dc http://docs.scylladb.com/procedures/create_cluster/ or multi dc http://docs.scylladb.com/procedures/create_cluster_multidc/.

Answer (score 1):

You need set rpc_address on scylla.yaml and while connecting through cql give your  rpc_address as well cqlsh xx.xxx.xxx.xx with user/pass if enabled.